# Handling various timestamp with one formatter in java/scala?

Tags: java, scala, datetime

I am currently getting two version of timestamp format eg `'2017-04-17 20:33:45.223+05:30'` and `'2017-04-17 20:33:45+05:30'`.My parsing is failing due to dynamic timestamp .Is it possible to handle both of these time stamp with one  DateTimeFormatter Pattern .Below is the example code what i tried

```
val myDate=LocalDateTime.parse("2017-04-17 20:33:45.223+05:30", DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")).toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC)//this will fail if  time stamp comes with '2017-04-17 20:33:45+05:30
```

I had seen one way to achieve the same using optional part however I canot make it work

```
val pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss[.SSS]Z"
val fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern)
val temporalAccessor = fmt.parse("2017-04-17 20:33:45.223+05:30")
```

Ant help on this or any suggestion how to handle such cases will be helpful .Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### uuuu-MM-dd

Edit: This fixes it. I am using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, and Java syntax.

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER
        = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss[.SSS]xxx", Locale.ROOT);
```

Trying it out:

```
    String[] variants = {
            "2017-04-17 20:33:45.223+05:30",
            "2017-04-17 20:33:45+05:30",
            // Variants we don’t want to accept
            "2017-04-17 20:00+05:30",
            "2017-04-17 20:00:00.000000+05:30" };
    
    for (String inputString : variants) {
        try {
            OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(inputString, FORMATTER);
            System.out.println("Parsed: " + dateTime);
        } catch (DateTimeParseException dtpe) {
            System.out.println("Invalid: " + inputString);
        }
    }
```

Output:

> ```
> Parsed: 2017-04-17T20:33:45.223+05:30
> Parsed: 2017-04-17T20:33:45+05:30
> Invalid: 2017-04-17 20:00+05:30
> Invalid: 2017-04-17 20:00:00.000000+05:30
> ```

### What went wrong in your code?

You had the right idea for your purpose.

You attempted using the outmoded Joda-Time library. Joda-Time can support optional parts when parsing, but not through the square bracket syntax. Instead its `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` has got an `appendOptional` method.

In your java.time code this part of your format pattern string doesn’t match any of your inputs: `MM/dd/yyyy`. Java parsed `20` as a 2 digit month number (postponing validation of the number) and threw the exception because no slash was found after `20`.

Edit 2: **why `xxx` works but `Z` doesn't**:

With Joda-Time’s `DateTimeFormat` one `Z` is for offset without colon, for example `+0530`. `ZZ` should have worked for `+05:30` with colon.

With java.time both `x` and `Z` (and also upper case `X`)  are for zone offset. Here too `Z` is for offset without colon. Either `xxx` or `ZZZZZ` works for `+05:30`.

### Use the built-in formatters

Original answer, likely useful for others: This one does it (using Java syntax):

```
private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
        .appendLiteral(' ')
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
        .appendOffsetId()
        .toFormatter();
```

Let’s try it out:

```
    String[] variants = {
            "2017-04-17 20:33:45.223+05:30",
            "2017-04-17 20:33:45+05:30",
            "2017-04-17 20:00+05:30",
            "2017-04-17 20:00:00.000000+05:30" };

    
    for (String inputString : variants) {
        OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(inputString, FORMATTER);
        System.out.println(dateTime);
    }
```

Output:

> ```
> 2017-04-17T20:33:45.223+05:30
> 2017-04-17T20:33:45+05:30
> 2017-04-17T20:00+05:30
> 2017-04-17T20:00+05:30
> ```

I am exploiting the fact that the built-in `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME` accepts a time both with and without decimals on the seconds. We can reuse existing formatters in our own formatter through a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`.

Comment: The problem with this one is that it will parse a variety of other formats as well.  For example - `2017-04-17T20:00+05:30`, `2017-04-17 20:00+05:30`, `2017-04-17 20:00:00.000000+05:30`. Can not be used for validation of input.

Comment: I'm curious why `xxx` works but `Z` doesn't.

Comment: Thanks ,It helped me As @jwvh mentioned why Z does not work

Comment: @jwvh Thanks for mentioning it, it deserves to be treated in the answer. Please see my Edit 2.

Answer (score 0):

[parseBest](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#parseBest-java.lang.CharSequence-java.time.temporal.TemporalQuery...-) looks a good fit for this

```
public TemporalAccessor parseBest(CharSequence text,
                                  TemporalQuery<?>... queries)
```

> Fully parses the text producing an object of one of the specified
> types.

> This parse method is convenient for use when the parser can handle optional elements. For example, a pattern of 'uuuu-MM-dd HH.mm[ VV]'
> can be fully parsed to a ZonedDateTime, or partially parsed to a
> LocalDateTime. The queries must be specified in order, starting from
> the best matching full-parse option and ending with the worst matching
> minimal parse option. The query is typically a method reference to a
> from(TemporalAccessor) method.

> The result is associated with the first type that successfully parses

Comment: This looked promising at first, but `parseBest()` is a `DateTimeFormatter` _instance_ method, which means that first off a formatter must be created with a pattern that recognizes both types of input forms, which is the original point of this question. It looks like `parseBest()` exists to solve a different problem.

Comment: Is `parseBest()` giving us anything in this situation? Wouldn’t we just want to parse into an `OffsetDateTime` no matter if the string has fraction of second in it or not?

Comment: Yes, but you can set up two ofPattern formatters and let parsebest work out which one applies. Or maybe I miss something

Comment: I think you are missing something. `parseBest` is a method of a `DateTimeFormatter`, so you cannot apply it to two patterns at once. Its point is that you can feed it two or more `TemporalQuery` objects, and it can return two or more different types depending on which `TemporalQuery` works. But in this case we don’t need two types since we already know that the result is going to be an `OffsetDateTime`. I should say that it is the wrong method to use in the OP’s situation. (@jwvh said it very precisely already.)