# How to return the correct dateformat with given input date

Tags: java

I have the below code snippet, instead of hardcoding the date formats in the procedure is there anyway which i can get the correct date format returned in Java.

```java
private String getFormatter(String datetimeString) {
    final String[] formats = {
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S",
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS",
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS",
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS",
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSS",
        "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
    };
    for (String format: formats){
        LocalDateTime.parse(datetimeString, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format));
        return format;
    }  
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I would wrap a `try-catch` block around your parsing logic inside the `for`-loop.

Comment: How do these formats differ, other than the millisecond field?  Please, elaborate on the error you're encountering.

Comment: Since the built-in `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME` accepts `HH:mm:ss` with anything from 0 to 9 decimals, I would reuse it here: `new DateTimeFormatterBuilder() .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE) .appendLiteral(' ') .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME) .toFormatter()`. Then you’re set. Are you getting a date-time string from a database? Then don’t. Retrieve a `LocalDateTime` (or other appropriate date-time object) from it.

Comment: Related: [Java LocalDateTime.parse with millisecond precision but optional microsecond precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54682028/java-localdatetime-parse-with-millisecond-precision-but-optional-microsecond-pre). Also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68721470/handling-various-timestamp-with-one-formatter-in-java-scala).

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```java
List.of (
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S" ,
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS" ,
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" ,
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS" ,
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSS" ,
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
        )
        .get (

                "2023-01-23 12:34:56.123456".length ( ) -
                        "2023-01-23 12:34:56.".length ( ) -
                        1
        )
```

Or skip all those formatters.  Replace SPACE with `T`, and parse by default.

```
LocalDateTime.parse ( input.replace ( " " , "T" ) )
```

## Details

Just check length of the text! Use `index = input.length ( ) - 20 - 1`.

```java
List < String > patterns =
        List.of (
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S" ,
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SS" ,
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS" ,
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSS" ,
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSS" ,
                "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS"
        );
String input = "2023-01-23 12:34:56.123456";
int minLength = "2023-01-23 12:34:56.".length ( );  // 20.
int index = input.length ( ) - minLength - 1;  // Subtract 1 for annoying zero-based index counting.
String result = patterns.get ( index );
```

See this code run at Ideone.com.

> result = yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSSSS

## No need for these formatting patterns

By the way, none of these specific formats are really needed.

The *java.time* classes use standard standard ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating text. With such inputs, there is no need to specify a formatting pattern.

Your inputs nearly conform to the ISO 8601 standard. Simply replace the SPACE character in the middle with a `T` to fully comply. Call [`String#replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)), that is, `.replace( " " , "T" )`.

```java
List < String > inputs =
        List.of (
                "2023-01-23 12:34:56.1" ,
                "2023-01-23 12:34:56.12" ,
                "2023-01-23 12:34:56.123" ,
                "2023-01-23 12:34:56.1234" ,
                "2023-01-23 12:34:56.12345" ,
                "2023-01-23 12:34:56.123456"
        );
inputs.forEach ( ( String input ) -> System.out.println ( LocalDateTime.parse ( input.replace ( " " , "T" ) ) ) );
```

When run:

```
2023-01-23T12:34:56.100
2023-01-23T12:34:56.120
2023-01-23T12:34:56.123
2023-01-23T12:34:56.123400
2023-01-23T12:34:56.123450
2023-01-23T12:34:56.123456
```

Comment: The gold is in the *No need for these formatting patterns* section.